# The Alien grid of pictures

Tags: visual

I am working at the US department of Alien Research. Yesterday I received this grid of pictures from an unknown source, but unfortunately some pictures are missing.
I have the feeling that this grid could solve some big mysteries about alien life and our universe. Or it could be something else...

[image]

Can you please help me find the 4 missing pictures ? *(draw them or describe them)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are

> consecutive digits, on their sides, reflected about a horizontal axis, on a colourful background. The "unreflected" copy is on the upper side in each case.

What we already see in the grid is

> 1, _, _ // 4, 5, 6, // 7, _, _

so we need to add

> 2 (giving a sort of triangle-plus-hooks-on-the-right thing), 3 (giving a sort of astroid-plus-hooks-left-and-right thing), 8 (giving four touching circles, or some slight variation thereon), and 9 (giving two circles with a sort of tail to the left).

They probably

> were not produced by aliens.

Comment: Oh, really :( It might be just a joke from a kid then. Thanks for solving it, that was quick !

Answer (score 1):

I drew a picture to complete the puzzle:

[image: alien number grid]